# How to print validation error outside of field constructor in Play framework 2

Tags: validation, scala, view, playframework, playframework-2.0

How can I show a validation error for a form field outside of a field constructor in Play framework 2?  Here is what I tried:

```
@eventForm.("name").error.message
```

And I get this error:

```
value message is not a member of Option[play.api.data.FormError]
```

I'm confused because in the [api docs](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/scala/play/api/data/FormError.html) it says message is a member of FormError.  Also this works fine for global errors:

```
@eventForm.globalError.message
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get a better grasp of it checking [Form's sourcecode here](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/data/Form.scala)

`Form` defines an apply method:

```
 def apply(key: String): Field = Field(
    this,
    key,
    constraints.get(key).getOrElse(Nil),
    formats.get(key),
    errors.collect { case e if e.key == key => e },
    data.get(key))
```

That, as said in the doc, returns any field, even if it doesn't exist. And a `Field` has an `errors` member which returns a `Seq[FormError]`:

So, you could do something like that (for the `Seq[FormError]`):

```
eventForm("name").errors.foreach { error =>
  <div>@error.message</div>
}
```

Or (for the `Option[FormError]`)

```
eventForm("name").error.map { error =>
  <div>@error.message</div>
}
```

Or, you could use `Form` `errors`:

```
  def errors(key: String): Seq[FormError] = errors.filter(_.key == key)
```

And get all errors of a given key. Like this (for the `Seq[FormError]`):

```
eventForm.errors("name").foreach { error =>
      <div>@error.message</div>
}
```

Or (for the `Option[FormError]`)

```
eventForm.error("name").map { error =>
          <div>@error.message</div>
}
```

If you want more details, check the source code. It's well written and well commented.

Cheers!

**EDIT:**

As biesior commented: to show human readable pretty messages with different languages you have to check how play works I18N out [here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaI18N)

To be thorough you're probably going to have to deal with I18N. It's not hard at all to get it all working. 
After reading the [documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaI18N) you may still find yourself a bit consufed. I'll give you a little push. Add a `messages` file to your `conf` folder and you can copy its content from [here](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/resources/messages). That way you'll have more control over the default messages. Now, in your view, you should be able to do something like that:

```
eventForm.errors("name").foreach { error =>
          <div>@Messages(error.message, error.args: _*)</div>
}
```

For instance, if `error.message` were `error.invalid` it would show the message previously defined in the `conf/messages` file `Invalid value`. `args` define some arguments that your error message may handle. For instance, if you were handling an `error.min`, an `arg` could be the minimum value required. In your message you just have to follow the `{n}` pattern, where n is the order of your argument.

Of course, you're able to define your own messages like that:

```
error.futureBirthday=Are you sure you're born in the future? Oowww hay, we got ourselves a time traveler!
```

And in your controller you could check your form like that (just one line of code to show you the feeling of it)

```
"year" -> number.verifying("error.furtureBirthday", number <= 2012) // 2012 being the current year
```

If you want to play around with languages, just follow the documentation.

Cheers, again!

Comment: Just tip, of course for displaying human readable message it should be used as `<div> @Messages(error.message)</div>` instead of `<div>@error.message</div>`

Comment: Yeap, I18N is another story

Comment: So I guess I actually need to learn scala to use play.  wleao, your examples worked.  I did need to use @Messages(error.message) to get a human readable message, as biesior said.

Comment: I was looking everywhere, how to pass the additional arguments to @Message(..), good post

Answer (score 3):

As you said yourself, `message` is a member of `FormError`, but you have an `Option[FormError]`. You could use

```
eventForm("name").error.map(_.message).getOrElse("")
```

That gives you the message, if there is an error, and `""` if there isn't.